# Hbase master service is shutting down automatically after some time

Tags: hbase

I have tried to Apache start Hadoop cluster. All services of Hadoop and Hbase started fine. But after sometime HMaster in namenode and secondary namenode are automatically shutting down.

Below is the error log:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the answar. clean the data folder inside the zookeeper except myid file.
After that I have restarted the hadoop cluster. Now hbase is working fine.